# how to check xmlrpc default time?

Tags: xml-rpc, freeswitch

I need to know how we could check the default time for xmlrpc timeout.
am facing this while calling is running in local
is there any possibility to get to know the default time for freeswitch configuration file ?

I need to know how we could check the default time for xmlrpc timeout.
am facing this while calling is running in local
is there any possibility to get to know the default time for freeswitch configuration file